# VisualVM how to use 'JConsole Plugins Container' plugin

Tags: visualvm, jconsole

I have installed VisualVM JConsole plugin. not able to find any document to how to invoke jconsole from VisualVM. I get below option.

my question is: What Jar file I need to add?, and how to use Jconsole from VisualVM?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VisualVM is replacement for JConsole, so it does not make sense to use Jconsole from VisualVM. JConsole Plugins Container adds support for using existing JConsole plugins (like [JTop](https://dzone.com/articles/visualizing-threads-jconsole)) inside VisualVM.

Comment: Thanks thats how I am using the plugin.

Comment: Except JConsole has a builtin "Detect Deadlock" button that VIsualVM lacks.

Comment: No, VisualVM can detect deadlock(s) automagically. :-)